# SQL, Updates,and Inserts

Tags: sql, updates

Hey so i'm supposed to write a procedure AddSaleDetail that will add a sale detail for a book purchased and will update the sale with that book information. The data that needs to be passed in is  sale number, ISBN and quantity. And i have to RaiseErrors for the following things which i have already done.
The ISBN and sale numbers are not valid 
The ISBN is already on that sale.

And if there aren't any errors i have to insert the Sale Detail record into SaleDetail table. The selling price will be the Suggested Price for that ISBN.

Now everything i've got until the next two things that need to be done, this is where i'm unable to proceed.

Update the book in the Title table to reduce the number in stock by the quantity 
Update the Sale record subtotal, total and GST fields in Sale table to include the sale amount of the book purchased.

Here is what i have:
**ORIGINAL**

```
Create Procedure AddSaleDetail
(
@salenumber int,
@ISBN char(10),
@Quantity int,
@NumberInStock smallint
)
AS

SELECT sale.saleNumber, title.ISBN, saledetail.quantity,NumberInStock
FROM   sale INNER JOIN
   saledetail ON sale.saleNumber = saledetail.saleNumber INNER JOIN
   title ON saledetail.ISBN = title.ISBN

IF @ISBN is null or @salenumber is null
BEGIN
RAISERROR ('Please enter valid ISBN and Sale Number',16,1) 
END

Else
BEGIN
declare @sellingprice money
select  @sellingprice= suggestedprice from title where ISBN=@ISBN
declare @amount money = @quantity * @sellingprice

If exists (select * from saledetail where ISBN=@ISBN)
BEGIN 
RAISERROR ('ISBN already exists',16,1)

END
ELSE 
    if not exists (select * from saledetail where saleNumber=@salenumber)
    BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Sale Number Does not exist',16,1)
    END

        ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO saledetail(ISBN,saleNumber, sellingprice)
            values (@ISBN,@salenumber,@sellingprice )           
        END
        END
            Else
            BEGIN
            Update title(NumberInStock =@NumberInStock - @Quantity where    ISBN=@ISBN)
```

**Current**

```
Create Procedure AddSaleDetail
(
@salenumber int,
@ISBN char(10),
@Quantity int,
@NumberInStock smallint
)
AS

SELECT sale.saleNumber, title.ISBN, saledetail.quantity,NumberInStock
FROM   sale INNER JOIN
   saledetail ON sale.saleNumber = saledetail.saleNumber INNER JOIN
   title ON saledetail.ISBN = title.ISBN

IF @ISBN is null or @salenumber is null
BEGIN
RAISERROR ('Please enter valid ISBN and Sale Number',16,1) 
END

Else
BEGIN
declare @sellingprice money
select  @sellingprice= suggestedprice from title where ISBN=@ISBN
declare @amount money = @quantity * @sellingprice

 If exists (select * from saledetail where ISBN=@ISBN)

BEGIN 
RAISERROR ('ISBN already exists',16,1)

END
ELSE 
    if not exists (select * from saledetail where saleNumber=@salenumber)
    BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Sale Number Does not exist',16,1)
    END

    ELSE
        Begin Transaction
        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO saledetail(ISBN,saleNumber, sellingprice)
            values (@ISBN,@salenumber,@sellingprice )   
            if @@Error<>0       
            Begin
            Raiserror ('insert failed',16,1)

            Rollback Transaction 
            END 

    Else
            Begin
            UPDATE Title
            SET NumberInStock = NumberInStock - @Quantity 
            WHERE ISBN = @ISBN
            if @@Error<>0
                Begin
                Raiserror('Update failed',16,1)
                Rollback Transaction
                End


    Else
            begin
            Commit Transaction
            END 
        END 
    END
END
```

Comment: I would advise against having business logic inside your stored procedure. For a variety of reasons, but mainly maintainability.

Comment: this one is for more educational purposes than actual business purposes, would you have any advice as to how i can proceed with this?

Comment: Contrariwise I would advise that you *do* put business logic in your stored procedures, where the logic is data-oriented. Databases are not dumb stores for values, they're smart and should be treated like the ladies they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this update:

```
UPDATE Title
SET NumberInStock = NumberInStock - @Quantity 
WHERE ISBN = @ISBN
```

The NumberInStock is a column, not a @ parameter.

Also, you can also do something like this, but you will have to create @total and @GST variables:

```
UPDATE Sale
SET subtotal = @amount,
total = @total,
GST = @GST
WHERE sale.saleNumber = @salenumber
```

I think your first SELECT query is not very useful.  Your procedure will print out everything.  But you already have the parameters you need, right?  They are input parameters.  I hope this helps?

Comment: so i get a couple of errors still like above my else for this line

Comment: Are you still writing "Update title(NumberInStock = ..." with a parenthesis? But the parenthesis is for the Insert statement. For the Update statement you want something like "Update title SET NumberInStock = ..."

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with your INSERT INTO.  I think you may be inserting with a salenumber that already exists.  That could conflict if there is the same key value already there, and it is unique.  How are the tables?  Is salenumber the primary key in the sale table, and something else the primary key in saledetail?  If it's not an IDENTITY field for PK, you may need to add some more columns to the INSERT INTO.  What are the columns in these tables?

Comment: okay so i've got this stuff left i've fixed most the errors, how would i proceed with doing these two

Update the book in the Title table to reduce the number in stock by the quantity 
Update the Sale record subtotal, total and GST fields in Sale table to include the sale amount of the book purchased.

Comment: I think you have to declare the total and GST variables, the same way you declared the sellingprice variable. Then you would have to put some numbers into these variables. You could put zero there right now, just to get the updates to work. Then you would use the two UPDATE statements I wrote above in my answer. I hope these would work without error?

Comment: okay so i've gone a different route and most of the kinks are out now, i've inserted Begin Transaction at the first Insert and a rollback transaction after it, is there any code i need to add to make sure that it does it only when need?

Comment: I would make sure you have all the SQL working correctly before you wrap it in a transaction.  Otherwise you are adding complexity before you have the basic stuff working.  When you are ready to add a BEGIN TRANSACTION, put all of the statements inside TRY CATCH error handling to check whether anything failed.  If anything failed, then ROLLBACK TRANSACTION.  If they all succeeded, then COMMIT TRANSACTION.  This is all an extra layer of complexity on top of getting the basic INSERT and UPDATE syntax correct.  So do that first.

Comment: okay so i've got the entire thing done i get an error when trying to run the procedure it goes as this "Msg 8144, Level 16, State 2, Procedure AddSaleDetail, Line 0
Procedure or function AddSaleDetail has too many arguments specified.
"
i'll edit the original code to the new one

Comment: Here's how you troubleshoot an error like that.  Go to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx) or Google and copy "8144 Procedure or function has too many arguments specified" into the search bar (without the double quotes).  You will find [pages like this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/a53d4bbd-e3dd-4d54-8f43-5983fe995e0c).  I'm guessing your EXEC AddSaleDetail 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' isn't quite right.  And you should really test a minimal procedure first.  If you get runtime errors, you should try stripping out all the error and transactions first.

Comment: If this has been helpful enough, could you accept the answer?